# Minesweeper increasing count of adjacent mine grids

Tags: java, subclass, superclass, minesweeper

I am writing a Minesweeper program, I am trying to write the code for which it will show how many mines are in adjacent grids, however I am getting an error saying a class is expected, I am not sure why.  I was under the assumption because both methods are in the MSgrid method it is ok. I have commented the line that is erroring as ERROR HERE. here is my code:

```
/**
 * Represents a single square in Minesweeper.
 * 
 * @author Sophia Ali
 * June 17, 2012
 */
public class MineSquare
{


    // Fields:
    /**
     * initialize variables
     */
    private  String  _shown;      // What a square is showing now
    private  boolean _mined;      // Square is mined or not
    private  boolean _flagged;    // Square is flagged or not
    private  boolean _questioned; // Square is question marked or not
    private  int     _minecount;  // Square's surrounding mine count
    private  boolean _opened;     // Player has opened this square or not



    // Constructors & Methods:

    /**
     * Default constructor
     * Sets _mined and _opened to false.
     */
    public MineSquare()
    {
        _mined = false;
        _opened = false;
        setShown(" ");
    }





    /**
     * Returns flagged status of square.
     * @return  _flagged    Flagged status
     */
    public boolean isFlagged() {
        return _flagged;
    }





    /**
     * Sets or unsets flag on a square.
     * @param   flagged    True or false (square is flagged or not)
     */
    public void setFlagged(boolean flagged, boolean opened) {
        _flagged = flagged;
        _opened = opened;

        /*
        // If Minesquare opened do nothing:
        if (opened == true)
        setShown(" ");*/
        if ( isOpened() == false )
        {
        // If flagged, square should show "F":
        if ( isFlagged() == true )
            setShown("F"); 
        else
            setShown(" ");            
        }
        /* else
        {} not needed but shows it does nothing*/
        }


    /**
     * Returns _minecount amount.
     * @return  _minecount
     */
    public int getMinecount() {
        return _minecount;
    }




/**
     * Checks minecount
     * If minecount between 0 and 8 _minecount not set and error message outputs.
     */
    public void setMinecount(int minecount) {
        if(minecount >=0 && minecount <= 8)
            _minecount = minecount;
        else //invalid minecount
            System.out.println("Invalid minecount in setMinecount: " +minecount);
        /*
        if ( minecount > 0 && minecount < 8 ) 
        {
       getMinecount();
    }
       else System.out.println("Error :" +  minecount);
        */

}




/**
     * Returns mined status of square.
     * @return  _mined   Mined status
     */
    public boolean isMined() {
        return _mined;
    }




/**
     * Sets or unsets mine on a square.
     * @param   mined    True or false (square is mined or not)
     */
    public void setMined(boolean mined) {
        _mined = mined;


        // If mine, square should show "F":
        if ( isMined() == true )
            setShown("F");
        else
            setShown(" ");  

    }




/**
     * Returns opened status of square.
     * @return _opened Opened status
     */
    public boolean isOpened() {
        return _opened;
    }





    /**
     * Open a square.
     * (Once opened, a square can't be unopened.)
     */
    public void setOpened() {
        _opened = true;

        if ( isMined() == true )
            setShown("X");
        else if ( getMinecount() > 0 )
            setShown(_minecount + "");
        else // blank space for _minecount = 0
            setShown(" ");
    }




/**
     * Returns openequestion status of square.
     * @return _questioned Questioned status
     */
    public boolean isQuestioned() {
        return _questioned;
    }




/**
     * Sets or unsets question on a square.
     * @param   questioned    True or false (square is questioned or not)
     */
    public void setQuestioned(boolean questioned, boolean opened) {
        _questioned = questioned;
        _opened = opened;
        // If Minesquare opened do nothing:
        /*if (opened == true)
        setShown(" ");

        // If Questioned, square should show "F":
        if ( isQuestioned() == true )
            setShown("F");
        else
            setShown(" ");  
            */
         if ( isOpened() == false )
        {
        // If flagged, square should show "F":
        if ( isQuestioned() == true )
            setShown("?"); 
        else
            setShown(" ");            
        }
        /* else
        {} not needed but shows it does nothing*/
        }


 /**
     * Returns what is in getShown.
     * @return  _shown
     */
    public String getShown() {
        return _shown;
    }


       /**
          * Increment _minecount by 1.
          * Calls setMinecount() to make sure that an illegal value (>8) is
          * not assigned to _minecount.
          */
    public void increMinecount()
         {
            int mc = _minecount;
            mc++;

            setMinecount(mc);
         }

/**
     * Checks shown
     * If _shown is one of legal values prints _shown if not prints error.
     */
    public void setShown(String shown) {
    if ( shown.equals ("X") || shown.equals("F") || shown.equals("?") || 
        shown.equals (" ") || shown.equals ("1") || shown.equals ("2") || shown.equals ("3") ||
        shown.equals ("4") || shown.equals ("5") || shown.equals ("6") || shown.equals ("7") || 
        shown.equals ("8") )
        _shown = shown;
    else //invalid value of shown
        System.out.println("Invalid value of shown in setShown: " + shown);
    }


    }

/**
 * MSGrid class that contains a 2-D array of MineSquare objects
 * 
 * @author J. Chung
 * @version CS-501B
 */
public class MSGrid
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    // 2-D array of MineSquare objects:
    private final int ROWS = 20;
    private final int COLS = 20;
    private MineSquare [][] grid = new MineSquare[ROWS][COLS];
    // Actual size of grid that we use in rows and cols:
    private int rows = 9;
    private int cols = 9;
    // Number of mines that go in grid:
    private int mines = 10;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class MSGrid
     */
    public MSGrid()
    {
        // initialise the grid of MineSquare objects:
        // (construct individual MineSquare objects within grid array)
        for ( int r = 1; r <= rows; r++ ) {
            for ( int c = 1; c <= cols; c++ ) {
                grid[r][c] = new MineSquare();
            }
        }
    }


    /*
     * MSGrid methods:
     * 
     * - Set mines
     * - Compute and set minecounts
     */

    /**
     * Set some number of mines at random within the grid.
     */
    public void setMines() //scattering mines
    {
        // Choose random row, choose random col, place mine there:
        for ( int i = 1; i <= mines; i++ )
        {
            int randomrow = randbetween( 1, rows );
            int randomcol = randbetween( 1, cols );

            // If square is already mined, do it again:
            while ( grid[randomrow][randomcol].isMined() == true )
            {
                randomrow = randbetween( 1, rows );
                randomcol = randbetween( 1, cols );
            }

            grid[randomrow][randomcol].setMined(true);
        }
    }




    /*
     * Compute and set square minecounts.
     */
    public void setMinecounts()
    {
        // Approach #1: Visit each square in grid; examine all adjacent
        //              squares; for each mine found, increment minecount
        //              by 1.

        // Approach #2: Visit each mined square in grid; increment minecount
        //              of all adjacent squares by 1. plus one for all neighbors of mined grid (even if it already +1) - easier way to do it
            //**do nested for loop to access every square in grid
    for ( int r = 1; r <= rows; r++ ) {
           for ( int c = 1; c <= cols; c++ ) {
                // if current square at r,c has a mine:
            if ( grid[r][c].isMined() == true )
            {    
                if (grid[r][c].isValidSquare(int rr, int cc) == true) //***ERROR HERE***
                {
                    grid[r-1][c-1].increMinecount();
                    grid[r][c-1].increMinecount();
                    grid[r+1][c-1].increMinecount();
                    grid[r+1][c].increMinecount();
                    grid[r-1][c].increMinecount();
                    grid[r+1][c+1].increMinecount();
                    grid[r][c+1].increMinecount();
                    grid[r-1][c+1].increMinecount();
            }    
            }
        }
    }
}
  // Note: In both approaches, must exclude squares that are not in grid.
  //       (Must use the isValidSquare() method below.)





    /*
     * See if a square at some row, col is within the grid.
     * 
     * @param   rr row of square in question
     * @param   cc col of square in question
     * @return  True if square is in grid, false if square not in grid
     */
    private boolean isValidSquare( int rr, int cc )
    {
        if ( rr >= 1 && rr <= rows && cc >= 1 && cc <= cols )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }






    /**
     * Show the grid, for testing purposes only.
     */
    public void showMSGrid()
    {
        for ( int r = 1; r <= rows; r++ ) {
            for ( int c = 1; c <= cols; c++ ) {
                // Call a MineSquare method:
                int mc = grid[r][c].getMinecount();

                // Show a mine or a minecount number:
                if ( grid[r][c].isMined() == true )
                    System.out.print(" " + "X" );
                else
                    System.out.print(" " + mc);
            } // end of column

            System.out.println(); // line break

        } // end of row
    }





    /**
     * randbetween: Return a random integer between low and high values
     * 
     * @param: low - low value
     * @param: high - high value
     * @return: random integer b/w low and high
     */ 
    private int randbetween( int low, int high ) {
        // Make sure that low and high values are in correct positions:
        // If low > high, swap low and high.
        if ( low > high ) {
            int temp = low;
            low = high;
            high = temp;
        }

        int scale = high - low + 1;
        int shift = low;
        int randnum = (int)(Math.random() * scale) + shift;

        return randnum;
    }

    /*first setmines
    then setminecount
    then showmsgrid
    */
}
```

Comment: Please give us the specific error plus a stack trace. Lot of code, not that useful. The complete error plus stack trace very useful.

Comment: For reference, you should generally be throwing exceptions (like, say, `InvalidArgumentException`) for stuff that won't happen if the class is being used correctly.  Among other things, that gets you a stack trace, which is a hell of a lot more helpful than an error message at showing you how the code is screwing up.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want

```
if(isValidSquare(r, c))
```

instead of

```
if (grid[r][c].isValidSquare(int rr, int cc) == true)
```

- isValidSquare is defined for `MSGrid` and not `MineSquare`, but grid[r][c] is a `MineSquare`
- The other mentioned issues

  - using `int` as you have here is invalid(ah the irony) code.
  - `== true` here is optional.

You are now getting NPE because of an assumption that `if (isValidSquare(int rr, int cc) )`, it has 8 valid neighbours. This is wrong because if this square lies on the edges of the grid `( r == 0 || c == 0 || r == rows-1 || c == cols-1)`, then it might not have many of those neighbours

You need to check for each of those conditions before incrementing the mine count. for e.g

```
if( r > 0){

     grid[r-1][c+1].increMinecount();
     grid[r-1][c].increMinecount();
     grid[r-1][c-1].increMinecount();
}
```

Note that this is only an example, and you would need to check for `c` in this as well at the same time. Or you could use a function `UpdateMineCount(r,c)` which calls `isValidSquare` first and only then calls `increMinecount`.

```
 public void IncrementMineCount(MineSquare ms, int r, int c){
       if(isValidSquare(r,c)){
            ms.increMineCount();
       }     
 }
```

Now replace `grid[r-1][c-1].increMinecount();` with `IncrementMineCount(grid[r-1][c-1],r,c)`

Comment: thank you for your help. I have one last question,in the setminecounts method when it is an invalid grid it gives me a error saying" java.lang.NullPointerException: null", but i thought the isvalid method would take care of if it was not a valid grid, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @SophiaAli you are checking if (r,c) is a valid square, but then you assume that it has all 8 neighbours as valids squares, which is a false assumption. You might want to check each dimension independantly and then process the neighbours only if they are going to be valid

Comment: by each dimension do you mean each square? So i would need more of the "grid[r][c-1].increMinecount();" lines?

Comment: or do this over multiple times:    if(isValidSquare(1, 1))
                {
                    grid[r-1][c-1].increMinecount(); //8 times
                    
            }    
            if (isValidSquare(1,2))
            {
                     grid[r-1][c-1].increMinecount(); //8 times}

Comment: So would it make accomplish the same thing if i change this line from isValidSquare "if ( rr >= 1 && rr <= rows && cc >= 1 && cc <= cols )" to  "if ( rr > 1 && rr < rows && cc > 1 && cc < cols )"

Comment: @SophiaAli I am just seeing that you are checking  `>= 1` and not 0... There is a logical bug there.. Depending on what you want to do, it is either `rr >= 1 && rr <= rows-2` or `r >= 0 && rr <= rows`. Remember that in most languages, array indices start at 0, and thus last element is at `rows-1`. The first option will fix your exception, but you need to see if that is indeed what you want. That would just skip all grids along the edges.. If you are using the edges as a buffer, thats fine, else its a bug

Comment: Oh wow, just noticed, your grid starts at 1.. so you would need to rethink it, or do `rr > 1 && rr < rows-1` to fix the exception.. Key is to understand whats going wrong, so you can fix it correctly for your situation

Answer (score 0):

`if (grid[r][c].isValidSquare(int rr, int cc) == true)`

Isn't valid code. Try

`if (grid[r][c].isValidSquare(rr, cc) == true)`.

Also, checking is a boolean is true of false is normally done without using the true/false values. i.e. `if (grid[r][c].isValidSquare(rr, cc))`.

Comment: I don't think rr or cc are defined either, so probably `isValidSquare(r, c)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `grid` holds `MineSquare` objects. However your `isValidSquare` method is defined in class `MSGrid`. `grid[r][c]` will return a `MineSquare` object and so trying to invoke `isValidSquare` on that object is wrong. You will get a compile time error which says that method is undefined for type MineSquare.

Move that method to your `MineSquare` class and most probably that should be fine. Ofcourse, you need to fix the call to `isVaidSquare` by doing this `(grid[r][c].isValidSquare(r,c))`. It is after all a method call so get rid of the `int`s and change rr and cc to r and c respectively.

**EDIT**

Sorry, Didn't pay attention to what `isValidSquare` does. As @KarthikT points out, `if(isValidSquare(r,c))` will do just fine. If `isValidSquare` was working on some of the members of `MineSquare`, one can consider moving the method to that class.

Comment: the function checks indices of the grid. Moving it to the grid elements makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

If matrix contains true/false boolean value for mine presence in each square. Then this code works :

```
int[][] minesweeper(boolean[][] matrix) {
    int row = matrix.length;
    int col = matrix[0].length;
    int[][] newArr = new int[row][col];
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<col;j++){
            int count = 0;
            for(int x=i-1;x<=i+1;x++){
                for(int y=j-1;y<=j+1;y++){
                    if(x>=0 && y>=0 && x<row && y<col){
                        if(matrix[x][y]==true){
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(matrix[i][j]==true){
                newArr[i][j]=count-1;
            }else{
                newArr[i][j]=count;
            }
           
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```